# SQL Live Data (Tracing Tables and Views)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, streaminsight

I'm working on a WPF project, which I need to track the data in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I've a table full with SQL statements, some of them are "Select"s for the views and some of them for tables, but mostly views.

A WPF grid (in my situation its DevEx Grid) needs to show the -constantly changing- live data from my SQL statement.

That means I can't use any of Typed-Datasets, Entity Framework or LINQ.

AFAIK, I need some kind of pipeline, that i can pull the changes one by one and update the very related item in the data-collection.

Until now, I could only able to find some SQL Profiler-like code pieces to track the queries against the server and a new technology called StreamInsight.

I tried SQL-Dependency mechanism but with that I can't really track the changing item but the view itself. In that way, I still need to query the whole View/Table and put it again-and-again to the Grid which is an expensive thing to do.

I know its challenging but I really need to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: if you know the table name to render in your grid and even if such table costantly changes schema, doing a SELECT * would retrieve everything and DevXpress Grid would render all the columns by default, where is exactly your issue?

Comment: that's the thing, I don't want to pull everything, i just need to update the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check out following two options:

Change Tracking

Change Data Capture

You might already know about this, here is more information on them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519.aspx